# Android application name after deleted

Tags: android, package, google-play-services, rename

I want to change my application package ID, but I can not do this with an update.
The Problem is if I want to create a new application the name can not be the same.
My question is, if I delete my old application from the store, can I use the same name in a new application?.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. package ID's are uniquie throughout the play store, There cannot be two apps with same name.

And once you publish your app to the play store, you cannot change the package ID, but you can create a new application with same source code but different package ID.

Even if you try to push an update, google play console will reject, i dont think you could even make the signed version of the apk.

You cannot delete the published app ever on playstore, but you can unpublish it, then again the package ID will be used and you cannot use it.